# I was trying to add data to firestore but, "Firestore component is not present." terminal gives this error message

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write data to firestore.

I tried solutions on other questions. but could not solve the problem.
Here is the terminal output and createData function.

```
void createData() async {
  print("*");
if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
  print("**");
  _formKey.currentState.save();
  print("***");
  DocumentReference ref = await db.collection('member').add({'Index': _indexNo, 'NIC': _nicNo,'Name':_name,'Faculty': _faculty,'Year':_year,'Telephone':_telephone});
  setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
  print(ref.documentID);
  print('done');
}
}
```

> I/flutter (18061): * I/flutter (18061): ** I/flutter (18061): ***
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061): Failed to
>   handle method call
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Firestore component is not present.
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:906)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:88)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@18.2.0:80)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getFirestore(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:82)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.getDocumentReference(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:92)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin.onMethodCall(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:533)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:201)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView$PlatformMessageHandlerImpl.handleMessageFromDart(FlutterNativeView.java:188)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:202)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>   E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/cloud_firestore(18061):      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>   E/flutter (18061): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)]
>   Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Firestore component is
>   not present., null) E/flutter (18061): #0
>   StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
>   (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7) E/flutter
>   (18061): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>   (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33) E/flutter
>   (18061):  E/flutter (18061): #2
>   DocumentReference.setData
>   (file:///home/mamba/Software/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.10.0/lib/src/document_reference.dart:43:30)
>   E/flutter (18061): #3      CollectionReference.add
>   (file:///home/mamba/Software/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.10.0/lib/src/collection_reference.dart:58:23)
>   E/flutter (18061):  E/flutter (18061): #4
>   _addNewMemberState.createData (package:teamapp/Pages/addNewMember.dart:218:61) E/flutter (18061):
>    E/flutter (18061): #5
>   _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:513:14) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #6      _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:568:30) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:120:24) E/flutter
>   (18061): #8      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9) E/flutter (18061): #9
>   TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:204:7) E/flutter (18061): #10
>   GestureArenaManager.sweep
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #11     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:20) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:192:22) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:149:7) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
>   (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:85:7) E/flutter (18061):
>
> #16     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13) E/flutter (18061): #17     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
>   E/flutter (18061): #18     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded
>   (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7) E/flutter (18061): #19     _invoke1
>   (dart:ui/hooks.dart:223:10) E/flutter (18061): #20
>   _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:144:5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by this, refer to the GitHub link.
delete android and ios directories then run "flutter create"
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#generated-project-files-outdated